# Passing Selected dropdown value to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code.

```
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2"></span> 
<select name="status" id="status" onchange = "getText(this)" class="form-
control">

    <option>Select Status</option>
            <option>Open</option>
            <option>In-Progress</option>
            <option>Completed</option>
            <input type="" name="txt_holder" method="post" id="txt_holder" 
           value="<?php echo isset($_POST['txt_holder']) ? 
    $_POST['txt_holder'] : ''; ?>" />
    </div>
```

Here getText(this) is used to retain the value which passes to the textbox after submitting save button.

Below is the coding for Save button.

```
<?php   

/*          if(isset($_POST['Save']))
            {
                $Id = $_POST['Save'];
                $status=$_POST['txt_holder'];;
                $comment=$_POST['comment']; 
                if($status=='Select Status')
                {
                    $message = "Please select a status.";
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $sql2 ="Update faults set Status='$status' where Sero_Id='$Id'";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql2);
                    if(!$result1 ) 
                    {
                        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $message1 = "Records have been saved successfully.";
                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message1');</script>";
                    }
                }
            }*/
        ?>
```

The issue in here is, it will pass the selected dropdown value to the txt_holder textbox, but it will never goes to the database.

Comment: I hope those comment tags (`/*` and `*/`)are just for posting purposes and not really part of your code.

Comment: Yes it is.Can somebody help me please?

Comment: What is the datatype and value of `$Id`? Is it giving you an error?

Comment: <button type="submit" name="Save" value="<?php echo $row['Sero_Id'] ?>" class = "btn btn-primary" onclick="">Save</button>

$Id = $row['Sero_Id']  (Primary key of the faults table)
It's not giving any error.